# Why doesn't my aspect match a method which already has the annotation @Transational?

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-annotations

I've created a simple annotation (@ProfilePerformace) which combined with the magic of AspectJ should measure the performance of any method or class I annotate and print the results to Slf4j.   It seams to work for all un-annotated methods but doesn't seam to work for methods which have another annotation present for example @Transaction or @PostContruct.  Any ideas of why this is happening would be great.

I'm using Spring 4.2.2 and AsjectJWeaver:1.8.7 which is pulled in by Spring-Aspects.

Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface ProfilePerformance {
}
```

Aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ProfilePerformanceAspect {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfilePerformanceAspect.class);

@Around(value = "@within(ProfilePerformance) || @annotation(ProfilePerformance)")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
    String methodName = signature.getMethod().getName();

    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch(methodName);
    stopWatch.start(methodName);

    Object output = pjp.proceed();

    stopWatch.stop();
    log.info("Class [{}] Method [{}] Execution Time [{}ms]", pjp.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName(), methodName,
            stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis());
    return output;
}
```

Example of code which works:

```
@ProfilePerformance
public void delete(Item item) {...}
```

Example of a method which doesn't work:

```
@Transactional
@ProfilePerformance
public void update() {...}
```

**Edit:**

After doing some more digging I found these two posts on the Spring forum which seam to point to the same problem.

[Using-multiple-aspects-annotations-at-the-same-time-requires-annotating-interfaces](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/69305-using-multiple-aspects-annotations-at-the-same-time-requires-annotating-interfaces)

[Spring Jira SPR-6083](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6083)

It looks like it's possible there is an issue applying both annotations due to the fact my annotation (@ProfilePerformance) is applied using *aop:aspectj-autoproxy/* and @Transactional is applied using *tx:annotation-driven*.   In essence by the time my annotation comes to be applied the method has already been proxied to in order to apply @Transactional so my Aspect doesn't match.

I've applied the work around which is posted in the link above but I'd really like to understand if I'm doing this properly as this approach smells a bit funny.

**Workaround**

```
<!-- Use this instead of "tx:annotation-driven" so that we can register other Aspects on @Transactional methods. -->
<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor">
<property name="transactionInterceptor">
    <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource">
            <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</property>
```

Comment: Just checking some basics first.  Are both objects constructed by Spring?  If you add an annotation (e.g. @Transactional) to the delete method above does it fail to match?

Comment: `@PostConstruct` doesn't guarantee that AOP is already applied, proxies ar e created afterwards hence you aspect isn't active of the `load` method yet.

Comment: I tested it using two methods in the same class which is started by Spring using `@Service`.  One method had only  `@ProfilePerformance` and it works the other had `@ProfilePerformance` & `@Transaction`and didn't :(

Comment: I've updated the question based on the comments added. Thanks Dienum and Pace.